# Connecting to localhost redirects through proxy

Tags: rest, api, tomcat, proxy, postman

I am trying to call an endpoint on a locally hosted Tomcat server using Postman. However, when I make the call to:

```
localhost:9000/api/postMethod
```

it redirects my request through the corporate proxy.

I don't see any options in Postman and I have tried removing the proxy settings in the internet options, but the problem persists.

When I look at the Postman Console, I see the below. Why is it sending proxy-authorization and proxy-connection to localhost?

```
Request Headers:
cache-control:"no-cache"
Postman-Token:"{token}"
User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/3.0.11-hotfix.2"
Accept:"*/*"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
proxy-authorization:"Basic {auth}"
referer:"http://localhost:9000/api/postMethod"

Response Headers:
cache-control:"no-cache"
connection:"Keep-Alive"
content-length:"8063"
content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
pragma:"no-cache"
proxy-connection:"Keep-Alive"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my http_proxy system environment variable set. Looks like it's working once I removed it and restarted Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the following environment variables (I do it in .bashrc file):

```
$ env | grep PROXY
HTTP_PROXY=myProxy:9999
HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy:9999
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Then, you have to tell Postman to use the System Proxy in the Proxy settings section. It's just annoying because you can set your proxy in the settings, but you can't set no proxy hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck behind a corporate proxy or similar and you're using automatic proxy configuration which won't let you allow to connect to `localhost` addresses, this is what helped me:

Try using your IP address instead of `localhost` as a host name in your client application, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/...`